# Can we kill inetd if there's nothing using it / no config?

Tags: startup, embedded, services, inetd

In a small embedded Linux Busybox based system, by default **inetd** is being started at boot but **inetd.conf** has *every* service commented out as none of them are being used.

Does this mean we can just remove the call to start **inetd** or could it be required by some system process down the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to run `inetd` unless it's being used.

If you were really cautious you could look for uncommented non-blank lines in `/etc/inetd.conf` and only start the daemon if one or more was found. This implies that you would be changing your system configuration at some point in the future. If you're not doing that then you can consider the situation right now, and simply discard `inetd`.